# Analyze runtime for polynomial and exponential function

Tags: java

So I have been trying to implement 2 functions:

1. Method to perform integer polynomial evaluation in O(d) time where d is the degree of the polynomial.
2. Calculate exponentiation. I'd need it to perform in 0(log b) time

Here is what I've come up so far:

```
public static int polynomialEvaluation(int[] coefficients, int x){
    int n = coefficients.length -1;
    int y = coefficients[n];

    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){
        y = coefficients[i] + (x*y);

    }

    return y;
}


public static int exponentiation(int a, int b) {

    int res = 1;
    while (b > 0) {
        res = res * a;
        b--;
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

Does any of those 2 meet the time complexity requirement? I think I had the exponent function but not sure the cost of the 1st one.

Edited: I rewrote exponential function trying avoid iteration loop as following. It might compute more efficiently now in my opinion

```
public static int exponentiation(int a, int b) {

    if ( b == 0) return 1;
    int res = exponentiation(a, b/2);
    if (a % 2 == 0)
        return res * res;
    else 
        return (a * res * res);
}
```

Comment: Your polynomial eval is wrong I think -- it's not calculating the right thing. The exponentiation is also not O(log b), what you wrote is O(b).

Comment: I did run a junit test and polynomial passed all the tests as it should. Regarding exponentiation I can't think of the way to do it without a loop just yet

Comment: Pretty sure your polynomial is wrong though. Consider evaluating `3x^2 + 2x + 1` at `x=2`; that should be 17 but your algorithm gives 41.  edit: AH! I see it now, `n-1` in the loop. Caught me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic algebraic operations (such as addition and multiplication), array lookups, and assignments are all considered to take constant time. Since your code only consists of these operations in a loop, the complexity is the number of iterations of the loop (plus a constant for the operations outside, but that disappears in the O notation). How many iterations do each of your loops perform?

This will hopefully tell you that the polynomial calculation has the desired complexity while the exponential one does not. Hint for a better algorithm: If you have already computed *b<sup>2</sup>*, what is the fastest way to use that answer to compute *b<sup>4</sup>*? And if you have that result, how can you compute *b<sup>8</sup>*? If you have computed e.g. *b<sup>2</sup>*, *b<sup>4</sup>*, *b<sup>8</sup>*, *b<sup>16</sup>*, *b<sup>32</sup>*, and *b<sup>64</sup>* in this manner (and, of course, you still have the original *b<sup>1</sup>*), how can you use these results to compute e.g. *b<sup>93</sup>*?

Comment: Thanks for the advice on exponential. Would you say the modified version in the 1st post is more elegant and faster?

Comment: @Walle: Absolutely! Make sure you understand _why_ the runtime is _O(lg b)_, though.